# Need to remove the method that is added to Folder.Items.ItemAdd EventHandler?

Tags: outlook, eventhandler

I added a custom method to the Folder.Items.ItemAdd EventHandler during the Button click event in the Ribbon control of a Compose Email.

Now, Every time I click the button the EventHandler Item is getting added again and again.

So, because of it the custom method is calling n number of times for n number of clicks to the button.

I Need to check whether the custom method is already added to that Folder.Items.ItemAdd EventHandler

Please Help : @roopa, @Dmitry

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a common programming question which is not related to Outlook or ribbon controls.

In case if you use C#:

- [How to correctly unregister an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292820/how-to-correctly-unregister-an-event-handler)
- [Removing event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307607/removing-event-handlers)
- [How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)
- [Best practices for removing event handlers?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b08d6506-cb1b-4bd1-a057-1ce9f67b4432/best-practices-for-removing-event-handlers)

Visual Basic .Net:

- [AddHandler and RemoveHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [VB.NET RemoveHandler & Anonymous Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447168/vb-net-removehandler-anonymous-methods)
- [Remove only one specific event handler in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487842/remove-only-one-specific-event-handler-in-vb-net)
- [explicit add/remove for Event in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647732/explicit-add-remove-for-event-in-vb-net)

Comment: Buddy: I checked the links. the method GetInvocationList, would solve my problem. and that is not available to any of the objects in Outlook.

But, I couldn't get the List of Events subscribed to "Folder.Items.ItemAdd". so from that list i can check "whether i have asked the handler to fire a custom method on ItemAdd event" @Eugene

Answer (score 0):

Do you not store the Items object in a separate variable? Check if it is already set and do not set the event handler again.

Comment: Eugene: C#4.0   Dmitry: how to check, if it already exists or not. That is my pain point buddy.

Comment: You really need to show the relevant snippets of your code. How/where do you keep the object that raises the events?

Comment: Class Ribbon.cs
{
data i = new data();
RibbonButton_Click()
{
 sentItemsFolder.items.itemsAdd+= new ItemADD_EventHandler(Items_ItemAdd);
 Mail.send();
}

void Items_ItemAdd(object item)
{
  WindowsForm w = new WindowsForm();
  w.popup(i); 
//this will pass the data class  details to the form and will display the form.
}
}

On all Email (composing mode), this button will appear. so, every time i click the Ribbon button. this event is getting added again.

So, this Items_ItemAdd method is invoked n times for n hits to the Ribbon button.

Comment: "sentItemsFolder.items.itemsAdd" would not work - you are using multiple dot notation, so the object that raises the events (sentItemsFolder.items) is stored in a temporary implicit variable. As soon as that variable is garbage collected, no events will be raised. Store the Items object in a separate variable (or list). An extra benefit is that Items.Parent will return the parent folder, so you can easily track whether a particular folder is being tracked by your code.